# UITableView Cells don't extend from edge to edge of the screen on iPhone X with insetsContentViewsToSafeArea set to false on iOS 11

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, ios11, iphone-x

In my app i have a tableView.

I want my app to work well on iPhone X in a landscape mode and my tableView cells to extend to the edges of the screen. I watched this: [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/201/) that describes how to adapt tableView to iPhone X in a landscape.

When I'm setting `self.tableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = false` in my `viewDidLoad()` method, it has no effect on my tableView in a Landscape mode (it rests against safe area as you can see on a screenShot, but it should extend from edge to edge with self.tableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea set to false).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In debug view heirarchy I see that my tableView rests against safe area, but in WWDC video, that describes how to adapt tableView on IPhone X, tableView rests against edges of the screen. I want to achieve the same result as shown in the WWDC video.

I even tried to add `cell.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue` but It didn't helped because evidently my tableView rests against safe area but not the screen edges.

[image]

I want my tableview to extend cells from edge to edge as it shown in WWDC video here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/201/

[image]

But I can't achieve this, not sure why. In my case tableView cells always not going beyond safe area. Something locks it from being extended, but I can't figure out what. I'm using custom cells from xib in my app. You can also notice a yellow topView at the top of the tableView. This is not a header, this is another view, but I'm not sure if this view can cause problems with cells extending to the edges or not.

I'm using iOS 11 and the latest XCode. I will appreciate any help and any solutions that can help me with this case.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this @Adelmaer? I'm still experiencing this in iOS 13.

Comment: did anyone have a answer for this question, I m stuck here

Answer (score 0):

have you tried removing this selection?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior) on UITableView

`contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

Unfortunately this doesn't give you control to change the scroll indicator insets.
[image: TableView]